# Forgot to unblock port 22 for SSH when setting up UFW. FTP port still open. What are my options?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, ftp

So the title says it all. I setup an ec2 instance on AWS running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a web server. When enabling the firewall, and opening ports needed for a web access (HTTP, FTP, ect.), I didn't think to enable port 22 for the SSH connection I use to connect to the server.  Naturally I'm unable to remote into my server via SSH to manage it since its now being blocked by UFW.  Luckily I'm still able to connect via FTP so I have access to all of the systems files.  What are my options to get port 22 on the UFW open?

Comment: also - unless you have a ***REALLY REALLY GOOD*** reason to run it, leave ftp off.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  This was a LAMP server to run my personal website.  What's another practical way to upload the files for my website?  Do you say that because FTP isn't secure?

Comment: Not only is ftp not secure, it's a very common attack vector: use key-based authentication, then use scp or sftp (same port as ssh is running on). Otherwise ***anyone*** who guesses your credentials can deface your website, upload junk there, make it part of a ddos, etc.

Comment: Great advice. I just watched a video on how insecure FTP is.  I had no idea.  I'll definitely be using SFTP moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

If you've done nothing else yet, blow-away the instance, and redo it. That's the best, simplest, and fastest solution.

Does Amazon have a recovery console for instances? I seem to recall they do. If they do, you could reboot the instance into a rescue mode, `chroot` into it, and change UFW settings that way.

You *might* also be able to upload a replacement `sshd_config` and move sshd to listen on port 80.

Then upload an httpd config that changes its listening port to, say, 8080.

Then reboot, and ssh on port 80.

Comment: Thanks for the advice warren.  I couldn't find a recovery console via aws.  I also tried changing the ports on sshd_config and ports.conf in apache via FTP.  Unfortunately when I setup FTP I didn't give my user permission to make changes outside of the www folder so I was unable to replace those particular files once edited, otherwise I think this would have worked.  I was trying to avoid redoing the instance since I already had the LAMP setup completely installed and working, but it looks like I'll just have to bite the bullet. Thanks again for help!

Comment: @TylerBrady - I looked, too, and cannot find a console option on AWS

Answer (score 0):

You could create a replacement ssh configuration file and change the port number so that it listens on a port which is open by default and then upload this using ftp and restart the instance of Ubuntu. This would cause ssh to listen on that port, by when you can then change the ufw settings so that ssh can work in port 22.

Comment: This doesn't work if they don't have SSH direct access - they will need to restart the SSH service, which might not work for them.

Comment: @Thomas Ward Rebooting will restart the SSH service

Comment: But that won'ot work if UFW is blocking the service.  That's the firewall - not sshd.

Comment: @ThomasWard - if UFW is blocking the *port*, it will work (as I suggested also). If it's blocking the *service*, you are correct. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Allow_and_Deny_.28specific_rules.29